# SQL Select: Take value from XML field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I'm struggling to pull a value out of an XML field using SQL Select Statement.

The XML field is Info, the table is results.

```
<Screens>
  <Results>
    <Result ID="54722094-8b36-4a01-b089-3ecabebbf962" DataResponse="" 
          DataAction="" DataValue="2" DataScore="0" />
  </Results>
</Screens>
```

I need to pull the attribute `DataValue`. For the record above, I'd be looking for 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant RDBMS. the answer is platform specific.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL Server it was this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Screens>
  <Results>
    <Result ID="54722094-8b36-4a01-b089-3ecabebbf962" DataResponse="" 
          DataAction="" DataValue="2" DataScore="0" />
  </Results>
</Screens>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/Screens/Results/Result/@DataValue)[1]','int') AS DataValue
```

### EDIT: Data comes from a table

Just replace my `@tbl` with your actual table

```
--test scenario with two data rows, one has DataValue=2 the other =99
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,info XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(info) VALUES
 (
    '<Screens>
      <Results>
        <Result ID="54722094-8b36-4a01-b089-3ecabebbf962" DataResponse="" 
              DataAction="" DataValue="2" DataScore="0" />
      </Results>
    </Screens>'
 )
,(
    '<Screens>
      <Results>
        <Result ID="54722094-8b36-4a01-b089-3ecabebbf962" DataResponse="" 
              DataAction="" DataValue="99" DataScore="0" />
      </Results>
    </Screens>'
 );

--this is the query
SELECT info.value('(/Screens/Results/Result/@DataValue)[1]','int') AS DataValue
FROM @tbl
```

The result is 2 and 99

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, I know that... The OP did not tell anything about repeated `Result` nodes... The name `Results` of the parent might point to this... I'll vote yours up as it solves a legit assumption. It's on the OP to decide...

Comment: @Shnugo: I'm just say that OP din't mentioned anything about this topic. Also, he/she should be aware about this assumption. Thank you.